# Converting Complex Math Equations in MS Word to LaTeX

Tags: msword, word-to-latex

I understand that this question has been asked before, but I have yet to find a solution that works for my specific case. I have several MS Word files that contain extremely complex mathematical equations, and I am looking for an updated tool in 2023 that can accurately convert these files to LaTeX.

In MS Word, I typed the math equation using Unicode in Word's math mode (for example to type the summation sign, I go to Word's math mode and type '\sum' and press space and the summation sign comes up).

Can anyone recommend a tool or software that can accomplish this? I appreciate any guidance or advice you can offer.

P.S.: An example:

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you created the "extremely complex mathematical equations" in MS Word. E.g., did you use MathType to enter the equation code?

Comment: @Mico I used Unicode in Word's math mode

Comment: Can you please add a few examples of complicated equations to your question? Thanks

Comment: take a screen snip  of the equation and paste into mathpix (free version) you will be surprised at how well it does

Comment: @MS-SPO here is the example: https://imgur.com/a/jyghoqA

Answer (score 1):

The software that I used is the Mathpix. Its very simple you just have to take a screenshot of the equation it will convert math equations into different LATEX format/styles so that you can copy that code easily.
I think in free version you can convert only 5 or 10 pics.